# Fill-up preceding cells in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table and like to fill-up by id the NULL names by existing names. As long there exists one in this id, otherwise leave null. The table:

| id | SubId | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | NULL |
| 1 | 2 | NULL |
| 3 | 1 | Werner |
| 4 | 1 | NULL |
| 5 | 1 | NULL |
| 7 | 1 | NULL |
| 8 | 1 | Rutishauser |
| 13 | 1 | NULL |
| 16 | 1 | Radak |
| 17 | 1 | NULL |
| 19 | 1 | NULL |
| 20 | 1 | Zai |
| 512 | 1 | Chiozza |
| 512 | 2 | Scarmiglione |
| 512 | 3 | Chiozza |
| 688 | 1 | Gschwend |
| 688 | 2 | NULL |

I do that with following code:

```
;WITH cte AS 
( 
    SELECT
        Name,
        id, SubId, 
        (COUNT(Name) OVER (ORDER BY id, SubId
                           ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)) AS MyGroup
    FROM 
        MigData.dbo.TestRowsPreceding 
), GetName AS 
( 
    SELECT 
        Name, 
        FIRST_VALUE(Name) OVER (PARTITION BY MyGroup ORDER BY SubId
                                ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS UpdatedName 
    FROM 
        CTE 
) 
UPDATE GetName 
SET Name = UpdatedName
WHERE Name IS NULL
```

My expectations is as follows:

| id | SubId | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | NULL |
| 1 | 2 | NULL |
| 3 | 1 | Werner |
| 4 | 1 | NULL |
| 5 | 1 | NULL |
| 7 | 1 | NULL |
| 8 | 1 | Rutishauser |
| 13 | 1 | NULL |
| 16 | 1 | Radak |
| 17 | 1 | NULL |
| 19 | 1 | NULL |
| 20 | 1 | Zai |
| 512 | 1 | Chiozza |
| 512 | 2 | Scarmiglione |
| 512 | 3 | Chiozza |
| 688 | 1 | Gschwend |
| 688 | 2 | Gschwend |

And what I get is;

| id | SubId | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | NULL |
| 1 | 2 | NULL |
| 3 | 1 | Werner |
| 4 | 1 | Werner |
| 5 | 1 | Werner |
| 7 | 1 | Werner |
| 8 | 1 | Rutishauser |
| 13 | 1 | Rutishauser |
| 16 | 1 | Radak |
| 17 | 1 | Radak |
| 19 | 1 | Radak |
| 20 | 1 | Zai |
| 512 | 1 | Chiozza |
| 512 | 2 | Scarmiglione |
| 512 | 3 | Chiozza |
| 688 | 1 | Gschwend |
| 688 | 2 | Gschwend |

I figured out that the first select with the count already doesn't fulfill my expectations.What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following approach -

Count the number of unique names per Id, then only updates rows where this count is 1 for rows where the name is NULL:

```
with n as (
  select id, 
    Count(distinct name) cnt, 
    Max(name) name
  from t
  group by id
)
update t set
  t.name = n.name
from t join n on n.id = t.id and n.cnt = 1
where t.name is null;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! It is not exactly what I need, as the preceding part is missing, but works with this case.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *preceding part*, perhaps you need to include sample data that covers this scenario?